# How to make Django test client send requests to different subdomains

Tags: python, django, subdomain, django-urls, django-testing

I am using the django-subdomains project to enable subdomains in my django project, which works fine.

However, when writing tests, I cannot figure out how to make the Django test client send requests to different subdomains.

It only sends requests to the root domain even if I change the ROOT_URLCONF to point to one of the entries in SUBDOMAIN_URLCONFS with `@override_settings`.  But it works if I directly change the ROOT_URLCONF in `settings.py` to the desired subdomain urlconf, which is obviously an unacceptable solution.

Also tried to subclass the Django TestCase class and set the "url" field to the subdomain urlconf but the request is still going to root, resulting in 404.

Finally, I tried to use `subdomains.utils.reverse` to get an absolute url, but the test client does not accept this at all.

This question may be related to [Django Test Client and Subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389109/django-test-client-and-subdomains).  Someone mentioned in a comment that a hack has been used to solve this.  Please elucidate said hack or even better, a proper solution to address this surely not-so uncommon use case.

Answer (score 1):

```
HTTP_HOST = 'rede.example.com'


class TestIndexView(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.url = subdomain_reverse('network_index', subdomain='rede')

    def test_render(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.url, HTTP_HOST=HTTP_HOST)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: What is the `subdomain_reverse` function? What is the format of URL it returns? I tried all kind of URL hacking to no avail so I'd be surprised if this worked.

Comment: I'm using http://django-subdomains.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ for subdomain management